# C# winforms Bind a Guna v2 scrollbar to Combobox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, scrollbar

I'm trying to bind a guna v2 vertical scrollbar to a guna v2 combobox. If I want to bind the scrollbar to a panel I just need the following code:
`guna2VScrollBar1.BindingContainer = Panel3;`
But when I try to bind it to the combobox, the following error occurs:

*Guna2VScrollBar: Bind scrollbar to selected control, e.g: 'Panel', 'FlowLayoutPanel', 'UserControl', 'ContainerControl' or 'TextBox', 'RichTextBox', 'DataGridView', 'ListBox', 'CheckedListBox' and 'TreeView'.'"*

Do you have any ideas?